# How to share the same variable between modules?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.JS with Express.js and I need to share a variable between modules, I have to do that because this variable is a pool of mysql connections, This pool creates 3 Mysql connections at the start of Node.js and then I would like that the other modules will use those connections without recreate other pools.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- make that variable a global one, for ex: `global.MySQL_pool = ...`. This way you can access it everywhere by using `MySQL_pool` as the variable.
- pass it for each module where you need it as a function param, for ex:

  var MySQL_pool = ...
  var my_db_module = require('./db')(MySQL_pool);

where db.js is:

```
module.exports = function (pool) {
  // access the MySQL pool using the pool param here
}
```