# Calling an object in main.js from a module in Electron

Tags: javascript, class, module, electron

I have an Electron app with 2 modules, one of them being the standard Menu. When I click a menu item, I want it to call an instantiated module's function.

The only solution I've found is to have my instantiated object being a property of the main `electron.app` object, which is globally available.

Here's my example:

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;

const WindowManager = require('components/WindowManager');
let windowManager = new WindowManager(); // <- I want my menu item to call a function from this object

const MainMenu = require('components/MainMenu');
let mainMenu = new MainMenu();

function initApp() {
    let menuTemplate = mainMenu.getTemplate();        
    let menuBuilt = electron.Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    electron.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menuBuilt);
}

function mainTestFileOpen() {
    console.log('File open test function in main.js');
}

// I'm trying to avoid doing this
app.testFileOpen = function() {
    console.log('Function is part of "app" so globally accessible...');
}

// I'm trying to avoid doing this too
app.appWindowManager = new WindowManager();

// Start the app
app.on('ready', initApp);
```

**components/WindowManager.js**

```
class WindowManager {
    constructor() {
        this.doFileOpen = this.doFileOpen.bind(this);
    }

    doFileOpen() {
        console.log('File open from WinwdowManager module');
    }
}
module.exports = WindowManager;
```

**components/MainMenu.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
class MainMenu {
    constructor() {
        this.template = [];

        this.init = this.init.bind(this);
        this.getTemplate = this.getTemplate.bind(this);

        // Initialize
        this.init();
    }

    getTemplate() {
        return this.template;
    }

    init() {
        this.template = [{
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [{
                label: "Open File",
                click() {
                    /** Calling a function in main.js does NOT work **/
                    mainTestFileOpen();

                    /** Calling an object in main.js doe NOT work **/
                    windowManager.doFileOpen();

                    /** If the function is part of "app" then it works **/
                    electron.app.testFileOpen();

                    /** If the instantiated object is part of "app" then it works  **/
                    electron.app.appWindowManager.doFileOpen();
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}

module.exports = MainMenu;
```

I think what I am not getting is the scope of `click()` in an Electron Menu template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call a function from a different module (every file in Node is its own module, which is different from the typical JS environment) **without first importing the module.**

It's not enough to just write a function in the main.js module:

```
function mainTestFileOpen() {
    console.log('File open test function in main.js');
}
```

And expect to call it from the MainMenu.js module. You must first `export` it:

```
export function mainTestFileOpen() { ... }
```

Then, in MainMenu.js, you can import it at the top:

```
import { mainTestFileOpen } from "../main";
```

Same thing with `windowManager`. It doesn't look like you're doing anything with `WindowManager` from main.js, so just move the import and instantiation to MainMenu.js:

```
import { WindowManager } from "./WindowManager";
let windowManager = new WindowManager();
```

And then you'll be able to do:

```
windowManager.doFileOpen();
```

**Side Note:**

You do stuff like this in your constructor: `this.doFileOpen = this.doFileOpen.bind(this);`

There is no need for this as the only way somebody could call `doFileOpen` is by calling it on the `windowManager` instance like so: `windowManager.doFileOpen(...)`.

The same applies to:

```
this.init = this.init.bind(this);
this.getTemplate = this.getTemplate.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I was doing something with WindowManager in main.js and needed to instantiate in there? How could I call windowManager.doFileOpen() in that case?

Comment: @gmoz22 You could put an `export` before `let windowManager = ...` and in your function `click`, you could `let windowManager = require("../main").windowManager;`

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559043/how-to-share-the-same-variable-between-modules) for some other ideas.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!